# Construction of "Eine zum Lieben?"

Tags: grammar

Years ago, Berlitz taught me the construction, "eine zum Lieben" as "someone to love." I'm a bit confused by this.

There appears to be an alternate construction, "um eine zu lieben". But the one above has *Lieben* as a noun and *zum* contraction of "zu dem," is that a gerund construction?

This question comes from my translation of the latter part of the poem I cited earlier, beginning with "fame if you win it."

http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/sleeplessinseattle/makesomeonehappy.htm

> Rühm wenn gewonnen.
>   Kommt und dauert nur ein Moment.
>   Was is wahre wirklich im Leben?
>
> Es ist die Liebe.
>   Es ist eine zum Lieben.
>   Einst gefunden,
>   Bau deine Welt herum sie
>
> Mach eine glücklich.
>   Mach nur eine glücklich.
>   Und du wirdst auch glücklich sein.
>   Und du wirdst auch glücklich sein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite complicated. First, "eine zu lieben" sounds quite odd to me; especially because the verb "lieben" has a (in this context) negative connotation of "making love" – in opposition to "real, true love". So I think this translation is a no-go in this context.

I think it's better to start with the grammatical construction of the English version. Here, I think the "to love" is simply the infinitive form. It's the same in German: "[Die Antwort] ist, jemanden zu lieben". So, I think it isn't helpful to rack one's brain trying to analyze that quite strange Berlitz translation.

So, I would propose the following (using most of your translation – didn't care about syllables and rhythm):

> Ruhm wenn gewonnen,
>   verweilt nur einen Moment.
>   Was ist wirklich wichtig im Leben?
>   Es ist die Liebe,
>   jemanden zu lieben.
>   Hast Du sie gefunden, bau Deine Welt um sie herum.
>
> Mach' jemanden glücklich,
>   irgendjemanden glücklich,
>   und auch Du wirst glücklich sein.

Comment: Without looking at your translation, I came to 'jemand' too. Aber was wäre mit `Ruh, wenn gewonnen - in einer Minute zerronnen`?

Comment: @user: sounds nice to me, you've just to add a 'm' to 'Ruh' ("Ruhm"), because otherwise one would think you meant 'Ruhe' (which can be shortened to 'Ruh' in poetic language).